# How to know in C# size of one container in windows azure?

Tags: azure

How to know the size of a container in azure, using C # language. I have hundreds of terabytes of files, so I do not work recursively. I tried with the following code.

```
var key = Util.GetPassword("Storage Account Key");
var accountName = "mystorageaccount";
var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" 
                        + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + key;
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
long fileSize = 0;
foreach (CloudBlockBlob blobItem in blobContainer.ListBlobs())
{
    fileSize += blobItem.Properties.Length;
} 
fileSize.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the codes you are looking for...

```
        string key = "";
        string accountName = "mystorageaccount";
        string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="
                                + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + key;
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        long fileSize = 0;
        foreach(CloudBlobContainer container in blobClient.ListContainers())
        {
            fileSize += (from ICloudBlob blob in
                            container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true)
                            select blob.Properties.Length).Sum();
        }
```

Comment: Just a note that if the blob count is high, it is better to implement paging using the BlobContinuationToken. Else the code above will timeout.